# How can I use Dante to proxify calls to Microsoft Azure (service bus protocol)?

Tags: proxy, dante

**Context and issue**:

- I have a web application running on a WebSphere Application Server.
- The underlying OS is redhat
- This application requires direct access to Microsoft Azure Notification services (through single URL, using service bus protocol)
- For security reasons I cannot allow this, all outbound traffic must go through a proxy
- The web application cannot be configured to use a proxy (missing feature)
- I cannot modify the web application's code
- I can configure the URL the web application is sending traffic to

**I'm evaluating the following solution**:

- Use the [Dante](http://www.inet.no/dante/index.html) proxifier (BDS license + package is available)
- Use the proxifier in server mode
- install it on the same machine the Websphere Application Server is running
- Have Dante listen on a specific port for incomming traffic from my web application
- Configure the web application to make it send traffic to the proxifier (change URL)
- Make Dante proxify incomming calls

In other words, here is **what I want to achieve**:

```
Web Application -> Dante -> internal proxy -> external proxy -> internet -> Azure
```

In order to avoid this:

```
Web Application -> internet -> Azure
```

**Questions**:

- Is it possible to do this with Dante ?
- If yes where can I find a simple example (Dante documentation is not that clear) ?
- Else do you have an alternative solution ?

Thanks in advance for your help.